# jQuery check if checkbox value in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, each, checked

I have an array of user id's like this:

```
var taskAssignTo = jQuery(this).attr('data-assigned');
var userArray = new Array();
userArray = taskAssignTo.split(",");
```

This gets a string of id's stored in the 'data-assigned' attr, which are separated by a comma.

I have tried the following to check each checkbox, if it's value is in the array, like this:

```
jQuery( ".assignTo input" ).each(function( index ) {
    var val = jQuery( this ).val();         
    if(jQuery.inArray(val, userArray)){
        jQuery( this ).prop('checked', true);
    }     
});
```

However this only checks the last item in the array.

If i was to `console.log(val)` like this:

```
jQuery( ".assignTo input" ).each(function( index ) {
    var val = jQuery( this ).val();         
    console.log(val);
    if(jQuery.inArray(val, userArray)){
        jQuery( this ).prop('checked', true);
    }     
});
```

I can see that all results of the array are returned from the 'data-assigned' attr. If i move the console.log(val) to here:

```
jQuery( ".assignTo input" ).each(function( index ) {
    var val = jQuery( this ).val();                
    if(jQuery.inArray(val, userArray)){
        console.log(val);
        jQuery( this ).prop('checked', true);
    }     
});
```

Again this only returns the last item in the array.

Anything obviously wrong with what i have done?

**FIDDLE HERE:** https://jsfiddle.net/Lvwhvadk/4/

Comment: Can you share a working code snippet demonstrating the issue?

Comment: yea sure, i will edit my question to include a fiddle.

Comment: Cant you add a code snippet here. See the `{}` symbol in the editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first element is also matching but as quoted in **https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/**

> If the first element within the array matches value, $.inArray()
>   returns 0.

Which makes your if condition false. So your condition should be `jQuery.inArray(val, userArray)!==-1`

Instead of this, you can use **`Array.includes()`**

```js
$(".editTask").click(function(event) {
  var taskAssignTo = jQuery(this).attr('data-assigned');
  var userArray = new Array();
  userArray = taskAssignTo.split(",");
  $(".assignTo input").each(function(index) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (userArray.includes(val)) {
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a title="Edit Task" href="#" data-id="1836" data-assign="" data-assigned="15,1" data-title="multiple users" data-content="<p>Task Description</p>" data-status="incomplete" class="editTask task-1836">EDIT</a>


<div class="assignTo">
  <p>Assign Task To Users</p>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="project_assigned[]" value="15">User 15</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="project_assigned[]" value="1">User 1</label>
  </div>
```